# Считаем пары если заданы НОД и НОК

Tags: python, алгоритм, простые-числа, теория-чисел

Код не проходит по времени.
Задано два натуральных числа A и B. Найти кол-во таких пар чисел (P, Q), для которых A является НОД(P, Q), а B - НОК(P, Q).

Входные данные :

В единственном ряде два натуральных числа A и B (A < 10^5, B ≤ 10^6).

Исходящие:

Искомое количество таких пар.

Пример:

Входные данные :
3 60

Исходящие: 4

Мне кажется, нужно как-то удачнее range подобрать чтобы программа ускорилась. Сколько не пробовал, ничего не выходит.
Или может есть какой-то более быстрой метод нахождения НОД и НОК?

[Ссылка на задание (на украинском языке)](https://www.e-olymp.com/uk/problems/1244)

Вот мой код :

```
def gcd(x, y):
    while y != 0:
        (x, y) = (y, x % y)
    return x

def lcm(a, b):
    m = a * b
    while a != 0 and b != 0:
        if a > b:
            a %= b
        else:
            b %= a
    return m // (a + b)
a, b = [int(el) for el in input().split()]
counter = 0
for i in range(a, b+1):
    for k in range(a, b+1):
        if a == gcd(i, k) and b == lcm(i, k):
            counter += 1
print(counter)
```

Comment: math.gcd(), math.lcm()

Comment: не, не прокатит... тут имеет место быть двойное нахождение gcd. Пишу код, подождите чуток...

Comment: Внутренний цикл надо начинать с i, потому что (2, 5) и  5, 2) она и та же пара.

Comment: lcm(a, b) = (a * b) / gcd(a, b) Смотрите вики: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%B5_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B5_%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5

Comment: Если внутренний цикл начинать с I, тогда результат будет в 2 раза меньше. А в тесте указано, что для 3, 60 должно получится 4.

Comment: @A_Vaclav увеличить результат в два раза намного быстрее, чем гонять в два раза больше вычислений.

Comment: согласен с вами, мистер Эникейщик

Comment: @Эникейщик, пары `(2, 5)` и `(5, 2)` в этой задаче считаются разными. Для `3, 60` получатся пары `(3, 60)`, `(12, 15)`, `(15, 12)`, `(60, 3)`.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy если мы нашли (2, 5), то мы нашли и (5, 2). Нет смысла проводить дополнительные вычисления, чтобы найти то, что уже найдено.

Comment: @Эникейщик, теперь понял. Я по другому прочитал ваш комментарий.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Перебирать пары *(p, q)* - тупиковое решение. Оптимальный перебор для *(1, 10<sup>6</sup>)* потребует *499999500000* (*= 10<sup>6</sup>(10<sup>6</sup> - 1) / 2*) итераций. Решать нужно по другому, без непосредственной проверки пар.

Вот решение. Пояснения ниже.

```
def n_of_prime_divisors(n):
    c = 0
    d = 2
    while d * d <= n:
        if n % d == 0:
            while n % d == 0:
                n //= d
            c += 1
        d += 1
    if n > 1:
        c += 1
    return c


a, b = map(int, input().split())
if b % a != 0:
    print(0)
else:
    print(2 ** n_of_prime_divisors(b // a))
```

Если *b* не делится на *a*, то решений нет совсем. *НОК* всегда делится на *НОД*. Далее будем считать что *b* делится на *a*.

Пусть пара *(p, q)* решает задачу для *(a, b)*, то есть *a = НОД(p, q)*, *b = НОК(p, q)*.

Тогда пара *(p/a, q/a)* решает задачу для *(1, b/a)*, то есть *1 = НОД(p/a, q/a)*, *b/a = НОК(p/a, q/a)*.

Следовательно количество пар для задачи *(a, b)* и для задачи *(1, b/a)* одинаково. Далее будем решать задачу *(1, n)*.

Задача сведена к поиску взаимно простых пар *(p, q)*, таких что *pq = n*. Другими словами: сколькими способами *n* можно разложить в произведение двух взаимно простых множителей.

Разложим *n* на простые: *n = s<sub>1</sub><sup>e<sub>1</sub></sup> s<sub>2</sub><sup>e<sub>2</sub></sup> ... s<sub>k</sub><sup>e<sub>k</sub></sup>* где *s<sub>i</sub>* - различные простые, *e<sub>i</sub>* - натуральные.

Для примера рассмотрим *s<sub>1</sub>*. Он должен попасть в *p* или в *q* или в оба, так как их произведение равно *n*, а в *n* он есть. Если *s<sub>1</sub>* входит и в *p* и в *q*, то *p* и *q* не взаимно простые. Следовательно, *s<sub>1</sub><sup>e<sub>1</sub></sup>* или входит целиком в *p* или целиком в *q*.

Сколькими способами можно распределить множители *s<sub>i</sub><sup>e<sub>i</sub></sup>* между *p* и *q*? Таких способов *2<sup>k</sup>* (*k* - количество различных простых делителей *n*). Доказывается по индукции по *k*.

Задача сведена к подсчёту различных простых делителей числа. В программе выше это делается элементарными средствами, так как нам нужно проверить только *√n* кандидатов в делители. *n ≤ 10<sup>6</sup>* - всего тысяча итераций в худшем случае.

В процедуре явно не проверяется что делители простые, это не нужно. Составной делитель не может попасть в счёт, так как его простые множители уже исключены из *n* ранее.

Пример:

```
$ echo 3 60 | python gcd-lcm.py 
4

$ echo 1 510510 | python gcd-lcm.py 
128
```

Comment: Спасибо, всё работает)

Answer (score 2):

Можно испробовать такой путь - разложение НОК на простые множители содержит **все** множители искомых чисел. А разложение НОД - **общие** множители.

Таким образом - отделяем из множителей НОК ту часть, которая участвует в НОД, и смотрим, сколькими способами можно **оставшиеся** (а для нахождения оставшихся сами НОД и НОК факторизовать не нужно, только их отношение) разделить на две части.  Сдаётся мне, что результат будет степенью двойки...

Пример подсчёта простых множителей:

```
 def factors(k):
    cnt = 0
    d = 2
    plus = 1
    while d * d <= k:
        while (k % d == 0):
            k //= d
            cnt += 1
        d += plus
        if d == 3:
            plus = 2
    if k > 1:
        cnt += 1
    return cnt
```

Comment: Вы правы. Доведете ваш ответ до ответа на вопрос?

Comment: Да, как буду у компа

Comment: Извините, не удержался, дал свой ответ.

Comment: Спасибо, решил по такому способу, хоть и пришлось попотеть

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
def gcd(x, y):
    while y != 0:
        (x, y) = (y, x % y)
    return x

a, b = [int(el) for el in input().split()]
counter = 0
for i in range(a, b+1):
    for k in range(a, b+1):
        tmp_gcd = gcd(i, k)
        if a == tmp_gcd and b == i * k / tmp_gcd:
            counter += 1
print(counter)
```

улучшаем:

```
def gcd(x, y):
    while y != 0:
        (x, y) = (y, x % y)
    return x

a, b = [int(el) for el in input().split()]
counter = 0
for i in range(a, b+1):
    for k in range(i, b+1):
        tmp_gcd = gcd(i, k)
        if a == tmp_gcd and b == i * k / tmp_gcd:
            counter += 1
print(counter * 2)
```

следующий вариант:

```
from fractions import gcd

a, b = [int(el) for el in input().split()]
counter = 0
for i in range(a, b+1):
    for k in range(i, b+1):
        tmp_gcd = gcd(i, k)
        if a == tmp_gcd and b == i * k // tmp_gcd:
            counter += 1
print(counter * 2)
```

Comment: Даже так по времени проходит только 20% кода

Comment: ок. Как советовал мистер Эникейщик - внутренний цикл с i начинать, итоговый счетчик * 2....

Comment: То же самое, не прошёл. Попробую сейчас способ повыше

Comment: Опять же по заветам мистера Эникейщика используем библиотеку...

Answer (score 0):

рискну ускорить ответ мистера @Stanislav Volodarskiy...

```
def factors(n):    # (cf. https://stackoverflow.com/a/15703327/849891)
    # изменено под пайтон3, Внимание! возвращает генератор!
    j = 2
    while n > 1:
        for i in range(j, int((n+0.05) ** 0.5) + 1):
            if n % i == 0:
                n //= i
                j = i
                yield i
                break
        else:
            if n > 1:
                yield n
                break

a, b = map(int, input().split())
if b % a != 0:
    print(0)
else:
    print(2 ** len(set([x for x in factors(b // a)])))
```

Comment: ну да, Но как бы не мой код... просто быстрый :-) извините

Comment: `int((n+0.05) ** 0.5) + 1)` -> `math.isqrt(n) + 1`. `isqrt` появился в Python 3.8. До него можно было писать `int(math.sqrt(n)) + 1` - есть гарантии что всегда будет вычислено верно для вменяемых чисел.

Comment: да да я просто забыл взять от set(list) исправил....